# Project Euler # 8- Find biggest product of n adjacent digits in number. Code works only for some values of n

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on Project Euler #8 in Python. The task is to look for highest product of 13 adjacent digits in this very long number:

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

For example, the product of first five digits is 7 * 3 * 1 * 6 * 7 = 882.

Below is the code I wrote:

```
i = '''73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'''

def mult(x):
    product = 1
    for num in x:
        if num != '\n':
            product *= int(num)
        else:
            continue
    return product

def main(x,y):
    z = 0
    num = 0
    while y < len(x):
        k = list(x[z:y])
        if mult(k) > num:
            num = mult(k)
        z += 1
        y += 1
    print(num)
```

After running the program to look for biggest product of four adjacent numbers (y = 4):

```
main(i,4)
```

I get the same, proper answer as in the description of the problem:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

However, after running it for y = 13, the output is 5377010688, which is not a correct answer. The correct answer is supposed to be 23514624000. Project Euler doesn't give any hints- It only accepts the correct answer or rejects a wrong one.

Why my program returns correct value for y = 4 but not for y = 13?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: In particular, what is the problem you're trying to solve, and what answer did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue has to do with you're getting your substrings. You're slicing a multiline string, and so some of your slices will include a newline character instead of a digit. Though your multiplication code will ignore those newlines, they still matter since they change the number of actual digits in the multiplication. If the maximum product you're trying to find straddles a line boundary (as is likely for a large `y`), you won't find it correctly as you'll only multiply one fewer digit than the question expects you to.

I suggest you remove the newlines from your string of digits before doing any slicing. The easiest way is probably with `i = i.replace('\n', '')`. (You can then also remove the logic to skip over newlines from the `mult` function if you want, though it probably doesn't a actually hurt much to leave it in.)

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  Your input is wrong.  You embedded newline characters in your digit string.  Try this initialization syntax, instead:

```
i = \
'73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934' + \
'96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843' + \
'85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511' + \
'12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557' + \
'66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113' + \
'62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749' + \
'30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866' + \
'70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776' + \
'65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243' + \
'52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397' + \
'53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482' + \
'83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474' + \
'82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881' + \ 
'16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586' + \
'17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042' + \
'24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408' + \
'07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188' + \
'84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606' + \
'05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725' + \
'71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'
```

With that change, I get len(i) as 1000 -- in your posted code, it's 1019, which includes the 19 newline characters.  Also, I get the correct answer (I solved that problem a couple of years ago, and kept the code as reference).

Comment: Instead of all the `+ backslash` you could also just put it into a parenthesis (no need for `+` and especially not for the backslash...)